# rails 3 route redirect error :id => "routename"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-routes

So I'm trying to have a link look up a method in my controller then redirect to a custom page with the path /trials/my_plays

I'm getting the error:
"Couldn't find Trail with id=my_plays" in the "app/controllers/trails_controller.rb:48:in `show'"

route:

```
match '/trails/my_plays', :to => "trails#my_plays", :as => :my_plays
```

link:

```
<%= link_to "Your Trails", trails_my_plays_path %>
```

controller:

```
  def show
    @trail = Trail.find(params[:id]) #48
    @member = Member.find(current_user.member_id)
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.json { render :json => @trail }
    end
  end

def my_plays
  @trails = Trail.all # once status is working, need to change to where(:publish => true)
  @follower = Play.where(:member_id => current_user.member_id)  
  @member = Member.find(current_user.member_id)
  @followed = [] #all trails followed by current user
  @follows = [] #the play record for that trail
  @trails.each do |trail|
     if @follower.count > 0
       @follower.each do |followr|
         if (followr.trail_id == trail.id)
                    @followed << trail
            @follows << followr
       end
     end
    end
 end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to "trails/my_plays" }
    end
 end
```

Comment: So what is on the line number 48?

Comment: Echoing @antonk you need to post the code for the show action. The error appears to be coming from the redirect to "trails/my_plays": `format.html { redirect_to "trails/my_plays" }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `match` route is being superseded by a `/trails` routing that sets the `id` parameter.

A resource routing for `trails` (or other matching route, like `:controller/:id`) needs to come *after* your route matcher, otherwise the routing won't get past the first route match.

Comment: I moved it up and when I view the page in my rails server I get the error:  No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.

Comment: Hmmm, and now it's messed up my trails index page, it's looking for the my_plays method.  Probably because the new route is superseding the index resource.

Comment: OK, I got it working.  I moved the route back down after the resources and changed the rout to just /my_plays instead of /trails/my_plays then in the controller method I removed the redirect.